# OpenLayers getCentroid problem

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a polygon from a select feature event. I can see the polygon using firebug but I'm getting an error saying Type Error: getCentroid is not a function. Can anyone help please?

```
var poly = event.feature;
polyCentroid = poly.getCentroid();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
poly.geometry.getCentroid()
```

instead of

```
poly.getCentroid()
```

The "getCentroid()"-method is part of the feature geometry, not of the feature itself:

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry